# API Management [Client to API] client authentication

Tags: azure-api-management

Firstly, this question is in relation to client to APIM and not APIM to a back-end.

I have successfully set up the Inbound Processing Policy so that it checks a client certificate by using the when condition = "@(context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint != "XXXXXXX") approach.

At this stage the client was using a bought certificate from one of the Microsoft trusted certificates.

The customer now wants to change to providing a self-signed certificate.

Upon sending the self-signed certificate, it appear the context.request.certificate object is null when presented to the policy.

I have loaded the same certificate into a X509Certificate2 object (via Import) and an invalid root CA error is returned, which is understandable as I’ve not loaded into my Trusted CA store.

For info at this point, the certificate contains the CA, intermediate and client certificate.

If I export just the client certificate from the p7b file and load that one into the X509Certificate2 object it works as expected – therefore the X509Certificate2 object doesn’t force the chain checking, which I guess would be done programmatically.

I have come across the `skipCertificateChainValidation` attribute but the context of the documentation suggests it's for APIM to back-end calls.